# how to use Local resource file in client side

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I want to use a local resource file string on client side without any jquery and javascript etc.

Currently I'm using code behind but would like to use in client side

```
awec.Text= Localization.GetString("ReqLodgeName.Text", LocalResourceFile);
```

like this. How do I use this resource file on client side for ASP control like

```
<asp:Label Id="awec" runat="server" Text='I want to access here' />
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you have the key "ReqLodgeName.Text" with value 'I want to access here' in your LocalResourceFile which is in the App_LocalResources folder, you may then use the `meta:resourcekey attribute:` in your label as follows to retrieve the text:

```
<asp:Label id="awec" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="ReqLodgeName" Text='I want to access here' />
```

Or may explicitly localize using a different syntax instead of `meta:resourcekey`:

```
<asp:Label id="awec" Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, ReqLodgeName %>" />
```

where `WebResources` is the name of the resx file with the resources in the App_GlobalResources folder and `ReqLodgeName` is the key name that has the text 'I want to access here'.

Comment: I am not using App_GlobalResources becouse i worked for a Client. I use App_LocalResources

Comment: @user1622434 In that case, consider using the meta:resourcekey attribute with value "ReqLodgeName" and your resx key should then be ReqLodgeName.Text

Comment: Does the resx filename in your your App_LocalResources folder match with the aspx page name with the label control? For example, if you have the page as LocalResourceFile.aspx then your corresponding resx file should be LocalResourceFile.aspx.resx and make sure the key name should be "ReqLodgeName.Text" in the resx file.

Comment: Yes i see your suggetion all thing is right and <label id="qwe" runat="server"><%= LocalizeString("ReqLodgeName") %></label> is working and for asp lable same thing not working

Comment: The meta:resourcekey attribute should work fine for your case since you are implicitly localizing your control, i.e. using App_LocalResources. Just out of curiosity, what's the name of the client page/control that is rendering the server label control?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. Add public method to code behind:

```
public string MethodName(string RequiredResourceker)
{
    //return resource depending on RequiredResourceker parameter
}
```

modify you client control as follows:

```
Text="<%=MethodName("RequiredKey") %>"
```